# How to dismiss a method when except block is run in a try-except

Tags: python, selenium

I'm just working on a simple script that goes through real estate listings and collects agents personal websites. I ran into an issue when I came across a listing where the agent didn't have a website in which case the script stopped working. Now i've put in a try-except which works until the except block is run, when that happens the whole browser closes.

```
    time.sleep(15)
for i in range(1,9):
    listing_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="m_property_lst_cnt_realtor_more_'+str(i)+'"]').click()
    try:
        realtor_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lblMediaLinks"]/a').click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: len(driver.window_handles) == 2)
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    except:
           print("Not found")
           continue
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.get(home_page)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Is there anyway I can revert back to the home page and start the loop again when the except block is run? Then if it's not; the loop runs as usual?

Comment: Does your actual code have the same indentation as the code that you've presented?

Comment: No it does not, i'll fix that real quick @acccumulation

Comment: `driver.close()` closes the entire browser, which triggers the `driver.quit()`. I don't see an easy way to close a tab/window when you have more than one going. As a rule of thumb you want to avoid switching window handles.

Comment: driver.close() was closing opened tabs without closing the entire browser before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, using exceptions as logic flow is not a good practice. Exceptions should be exceptional... they should indicate when something unexpectedly wrong happened.

Instead, use `find_elements_*` (plural) and check if the collection returned is empty. If it's not empty, that means that the link exists, click on it, etc. If the collection is empty, return to home and start the next loop.

```
for i in range(1,9):
    listing_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="m_property_lst_cnt_realtor_more_'+str(i)+'"]').click()
    realtor_url = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="lblMediaLinks"]/a')
    if (len(realtor_url)) > 0
        realtor_url[0].click
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: len(driver.window_handles) == 2)
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.get(home_page)
```

BTW, `.click()` still doesn't return anything so assigning its return to a variable will never return anything but `null` so I removed that part.

Comment: Amazing answer! I thank you, I actually learned something new and interesting there :) @JeffC

Comment: Hey @JeffC i'm getting a timeout error on the WebDriverWait, it's also not clicking the realtor links printing them out. It just clicks on the listing, brings up the page and sits there.